# Recycle view onScrollChange listener keep triggering rappedly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onscrollchanged

I am using the codes below to add vibration effects to Recycle view when I switch items, but I got the vibration to keep triggered the whole time I touch the Recycle View, I want it to activate vibrator only one time when items are changed.

```js
 recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener( new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) TeacherMain.this.getSystemService( Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(5);}

        } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL == newState) {//when finger touch it.
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(5);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```